# Python pickle load doesn't work when program is run again

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to store a class instance that contains one variable using pickle.

```
class Scm1:
  keys = {'b':0, 'i':0, 's':0}
```

The first thing I do in my program is check if the pickled file is exists. If it does, I attempt to load the data using pickle load. If it doesn't (this only happens the very first time the program is run), I create two instances of this class `t1 = Scm1()` and `t2 = Scm1()`. Then, in my program, I modify the entries in the keys field. At the end, I attempt to store the instances to a file. For this, I add the two instances to a dictionary -- `tmpDict = {'t1':t1, 't2':t2}` and execute a pickle dump using tmpDict as the object. When I load the data using pickle load right after the dump, I get what I expect (the data is set to what it was during the program). However, when I run the program again (this time the file exists) and load the data, all entries in the keys field for the two objects (t1 and t2) are 0. Why is it that when I'm able to get the correct results when I do pickle load prior to my program ending and not again when I rerun the program. I'm new to python and so I'm not sure if I'm expecting pickle to work the right way. Sorry for not being able to paste more code snippets as it's for a school assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Scm1:
    keys = {'b':0, 'i':0, 's':0}
```

`keys` is a class variable, so all instances of the class share it.  Class variables are not pickled when you store the instances, as they do not belong to the instances.

You should use instance attributes instead:

```
class Scm1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.keys = {'b':0, 'i':0, 's':0}
```